# Add Filters to Video like Instagram

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am coding for an app and need to apply filters to videos like Instagram.

I tried with FFMPEG library, but it doesn't work well and does not provide all filters.

What I tried so far is,

```
String commandStr1 = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/vids.mp4 -strict experimental -vf hue=s=0 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -s 320x240 -r 30 /sdcard/vid_out.mp4";

String[] complexCommand3 = {"ffmpeg","-y", "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/out1.mp4",
    "-i", "/sdcard/videokit/out2.mp4", "-strict", "experimental",
    "-filter_complex",
    "[0:v]scale=640x480,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=640x480,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
    "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "640x480", "-r", "30", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b", "2097k", "/sdcard/videokit/out3.mp4"};
```

Is there any other open source or paid library to apply filters to videos? Any kind of help to achieve this functionality will be appreciated.

or How can I make my own video filters?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of filters?

Comment: @Mulvya I already said, filters like in Instagram

Comment: Not familiar with Instagram filters - link to examples.

Comment: Hey @Mulvya again we need your help ! https://designpieces.com/2014/09/instagram-filters-css3-effects/ this is link to instagram filters .Can we achieve them with FFMPEG?

Comment: My question on same http://stackoverflow.com/q/43658031/5996106

Comment: See the [`eq`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) and [`hue`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hue) filters